# Can't prepare lesson material. Should I cancel class?

Tags: teaching-assistant

I'm a grad student teaching assistant for a freshmen undergrad non major multivariable  calculus class.

What they didn't tell me is that the second half of the semester is not calculus but "finite math". This week's topic is game theory, which I've never learned myself.

In preparing tomorrow's material, I realized I was getting all the answers wrong from one of the sections, and have no idea how to do the problems I'm supposed to teach. Normally it only takes a day to read the textbook and prepare.

I've been up for hours struggling with the same problems and need to leave in 5 hours to get to class on time - and would still like to sleep.

My school never gave me any training or told me any rules; am I allowed to just cancel class?

I'll take any advice at this point.

Edit: I would just like to say how much I appreciate everyone's responses. I'm running on little sleep, (and *extremely* new to Stack Exchange so still learning how the site works) but you've all given me great ideas when I was truly stressing out.

Edit/Update: turns out I was not doing it incorrectly, just did algebraic work when I should've used a graph so I considered points that I didn't need to which is why my answers were wrong. I met up with the individual who TAd for the course last semester and that's how I figured out my mistake. I sorta winged it in presentation and got the correct answer, now just have to repeat the lesson for the rest of the sessions.

Thank you all for your input.

**Edit** (from comment): Game theory is just one week of the course; they have two lectures with the professor prior to one 50 minute session with me. This is the only session with me out of a year long course that has been or will be like this.

Comment: sounds like a highly dysfunctional situation.  What I would do is go to class and talk about something I know (filibuster) until I can present any game theory

Comment: I would encourage you to roll back to your original question.  I found the edits contributed by @henning stifling and unnecessary.

Comment: Indeed, feel free to do as @aparente001 suggests. I believe the question is now more to the point, but you may think differently.

Comment: I think this link can help you: http://oyc.yale.edu/economics/econ-159.

Comment: Do you know about convex sets/optimization? Game theory requires convex optimisation, so you could start with this.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I wrote the initial post in a sleep deprived, stressed out haste so I'm sure it was poorly written. I do not know about convex sets.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the course description or syllabus? Sounds like a very strange situation...

Comment: Tried to watch the Yale video in the past; too sloooooooooow. Maybe that's my reaction to all videos.

Comment: I really liked the game theory course on coursera if that helps in any way:  https://www.coursera.org/learn/game-theory-1/lecture/JOAby/introductory-video

Comment: @JessicaB - someone will feel the need to anonymously whine on Facebook if you bring free chocolates to class. You just can't ever win 100% approval, so that can't be the goal

Comment: _"I met up with the individual who TAd for the course last semester and that's how I figured out my mistake"_ This should have been one of your first remedies, as it's a fairly obvious step to take. Your actual first step should have been talking to your own boss/manager/supervisor or whoever it is that convenes the course.

Comment: Sorely tempted to suggest that you just stick on a video; Game Theory is a [very common subject in film](http://www.gametheory.net/popular/film.html) - Generating a list of questions (matrixes and pop-quiz type questions) should be a doddle too.

Comment: How did you not know at the beginning of class what topics you would be teaching?? Isn't there a syllabus?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86953/can-i-learn-while-im-teaching

Comment: As I mentioned in a lower comment:I knew that game theory would be touched on, I skimmed the section, realized it involved matrices and have had no problem dealing with the last 9 chapters of non-calculus matrix-related material, so assumed this chapter would be just as easy to deal with - but was obviously wrong. I was just upset that I signed up to TA a course titled multivariable calculus and found out after the fact that there was more to it. The course is also covering linear algebra, probability, counting, linear programming, set theory, multinomial coefficients, etc.

Comment: @DVK I'm not saying 100% approval is the goal. I believe cancelling a class last minute would leave you a very long way below 100% approval. I said one student complained on Facebook (my comment seems to have been deleted, though I cannot see why). I don't know the reaction of the 75% of the class who never showed up to a single lecture I gave.

Comment: For people suggesting some rudimentary game theory solutions, like a video; keep in mind that game theory sort of falls off a cliff.  When you're first learning about the prisoner's dilemma, it's all interesting and simple.  When you get into the math-y parts of it, it rapidly becomes terribly complex.  Since this is part of a multi-variable calc class, I'm guessing it's much more complex than you're imagining.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would like to add on top of the answers of @aparente001 and @Anonymous Mathematician.

So, first thing, in 5 hours it would be very hard to come up with something solid that you would be comfortable lecturing about; thus I second the suggestion of doing some review and exercises for now.

My opinion is: **you can do it**.

If you have been teaching calculus so far, chances are that you are a very competent student. You can learn almost at the same time as you will be teaching. And this does not have to be a stressful experience, I would say you can be upfront with your students and let them know that you are learning at the same time as them (they already know that you are a student too).

Actually, this can be beneficial for both parts: *you*) are learning a new topic and because of that you better understand the difficulties that students may come upon; *they*) have a TA that understands their difficulties and that is able to explain things in a way that *a student* would learn (it may not be the best way, but I would say that is OK).

In the case they make you questions you do not know how to answer, again, be upfront: say that it is a good question, you will think and research about it, and you will explain it later, either in the class, e-mail directly to the student, whatever you prefer.

In order for this to work, like mentioned in the other answers, you have to talk to your supervisor and let him know that you were not prepared to lecture this topic. Ask him for help about learning those concepts, or a reference to whom could provide such guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a pretty good rapport with the students, and worked with most of them for their first semester of calculus in the fall ending with great reviews. I think being upfront with them is a good idea. Your response was a bit of a pep talk, and I'll admit I needed it.

Comment: That's very bad advice: telling the students that you don't know what you're talking about either just *never* works. The day after you will have 90% drop off rate or, even worse, 100% attendance with nobody paying a penny of attention to what you are saying.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco I disagree with you. I have experienced that both as a student and as a lecturer. It may depend on how you say things. You should not say: *hey guys, I know nothing about this*. That is not what I meant. It seems the OP is a good lecturer, from his reviews. If there is a topic that he may not be so comfortable, it does not mean that it lacks confidence. Conversely, I have had teachers which did not admit they may lack knowledge, the students can smell the lack of confidence, and the class becomes a boring and awkward experience.

Comment: To clarify, I did not suggest for the OP to *explicitly* say he does not know. Instead, I suggested something in the lines of *I'm learning this at the same time as you*, and when confronted with questions that he does not know the answer, *that is a good question, I will think and research about it*. The key here is to avoid using the negation and, of course, be sincere.

Comment: I've been in this situation as a student, and I couldn't take they instructor seriously. It's insulting to charge students for a class being taught by someone that has no knowledge of the topic. They should definitely not admit  that's what's happening!

Comment: Gotta admit, teachers who admitted they didn't know the material was a cue for me to check out. I was extremely busy in college, had a hard time making it to class in the first place some times, and this would just tell me that I was wasting that effort getting there since I apparently could learn just as well just reading the book.

Comment: *I've been up for hours struggling with the same problems and need to leave in 5 hours to get to class on time*.  I doubt there is anything in OP's contract that would require that he stay up all or most of the night.

Comment: @Kat You'd rather be lied to???

Comment: @JeffE I'd rather they got a competent instructor to teach instead.

Comment: @Kat Teaching is not just about knowing everything about the topic. It is mainly about conveying the knowledge from the teacher to the students. The OP seems to be competent in doing this (see comment about previous reviews). He also seems to be competent gathering knowledge from other sources. In my POV, this makes a good instructor. The fact he *just* learned what he is teaching should not be the issue here. I would like to refer the answer by [JeopardyTempest](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/86941/31419) which, I believe, also addresses a similar POV.

Comment: When I was teaching assembly language and learning it at the same time (as a tenured professor of mathematics, not a TA) I told the students up front. The best of them were on board (and one wrote better answers than mine on my first exam). I sensed that the weaker ones wanted to write the Governor to complain, but they stuck it out. I don't think they suffered.

Comment: @iled I agree. I've certainly had knowledgeable instructors that were terrible at transferring that knowledge, and that's no good either. But you can't transfer knowledge that you don't have, and you can't teach beyond the book if your only knowledge is from recently reading the book. You need **both knowledge and teaching ability** to be an effective instructor. Students don't go into massive debt for a talking version of a book.

Comment: @iled Some knowledgeable people *might* be bad instructors (certainly true), but someone who just looked through the text book a few hours before *can't* be a good instructor. Teaching a topic well requires intimate knowledge not just some coarse general idea. At least in Math or engineering. That said it's still better being honest, than trying to fake your way out of it - that never works if your students are even semi-competent.

Comment: @Voo I agree with you. I also believe that there is a middle ground here: for instance, I could read a wikipedia article about some topic that I don't know, but that I know the underlying fundaments, and then explain it to someone else in my own words, whom could not understand the topic by reading the same article. Something like that could potentially work for a freshman non major topic covered in one week, do you agree? :) Please, do not take my words in this answer and comments as absolute assertions.

Comment: @kat Oh, of course. But you wrote "They should definitely **not admit** that's what is happening," strongly suggesting that if it _is_ happening, you'd rather be deceived into thinking otherwise than to have the instructor admit their ignorance. I expect most students would rather know the truth.

Comment: @JeffE I'm not suggesting they lie and claim to be an expert. I guess it would let students know not to bother attending class. I don't think OP admitting they're clueless is going to garner the sympathy and understanding that iled suggests it will, is all. They may as well just cancel the class, imo. No students will take them seriously.

Comment: For reference, here's an older question where we discussed telling students about your lack of experience in the subject in detail: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75226/should-i-tell-students-that-its-my-first-time-teaching-the-course

Answer (score 31):

Use tomorrow's class for review of what's been covered so far, including problem solving.  Then go straight to your supervisor.

Do you have a graduate student employee union?

**Edit** (after having read the additional information in a comment -- which I just incorporated into the question):

The additional information gives me a different view of the situation than I first understood.

Now that I've gotten this fuller picture of the situation:

- Prepare your discussion sections more in advance, so you'll notice in good time if a particular topic needs more careful preparation.
- Try a different resource, and/or ask the professor or a more advanced student for help understanding the material.

Comment: We do not have a graduate student employee Union

Comment: @user71118: Clearly you don't, as any half-decent union would not stand for this kind of travesty. Sending people into class without preparation and with them not even having gotten an overview of what they're supposed to teach at the beginning of the semester. Not to mention the fact that the teacher/lecturer in charge should have known better than not to check whether his/her TAs have studied the subject matter at all.

Comment: I've learned that my school is overall quite unorganized. The Dean used to require that all TAs have an entire semester of training (since most have never taught in any form before) prior to beginning work. But the departments decided they did not want to pay the TAs for their time and cancelled the training. Over winter break they asked me two days before the winter Intersession semester started if I would TA a separate multivariable calculus course for engineering majors, the course was 6 days a week and I would find out the next days topic 6pm the night before. Very hectic and annoying.

Comment: @user71118 - The lack of training is pretty typical, I think, but not the rest of what you described.

Comment: @user71118: Seriously, you guys need to form a union. If the situation is so bad it might not even be that difficult. I mean, it's super-difficult and demanding always, but in your case it seems to be quite doable. What country/state is the university in?

Answer (score 15):

You almost certainly aren't supposed to cancel class arbitrarily, just because you feel like it.  If you admit that you are cancelling class because you weren't able to prepare adequately, you'll look bad.  If you have to cancel, your safest option may be to pretend you aren't feeling well or have some other extenuating circumstances.  Aside from the dishonesty, that will put a lot of pressure on you to catch up in time for the next class.  (If you cancel because of illness and then have to admit you really aren't prepared to teach this material, it will look terrible.)

Instead, I'd recommend the following priorities:

1. If you can sort things out in the five hours before class, that's the best option.  Do you have any friends who have taught the class before and could help?  That would be far more efficient than trying to figure it all out yourself while in a panic.
2. If you can't prepare in time, can you rearrange the material a little?  For example, you could insert a review of what you've done so far before you move on to game theory, or you could start by introducing just the aspects you understand, and delay the hard parts until next time.
3. If you are completely stuck and can't figure out any plan that won't humiliate you and waste the students' time, then it's probably best to call in sick and then work as hard as you can to catch up.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I could not sort it out in the few hours. I'll probably work with your second option, I was able to work through the first few problems so I could at least start there.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to lie.

Comment: @AnoE I "love" the way that twelve people have upvoted your comment but only four actually agreed with it enough to downvote the answer.

Comment: Guess there is a scale of escalation for these things, @DavidRicherby. ;)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Some people's downvotes are not publicly displayed by the system =)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some people might do the math this way: +1 for the first option, +1 for the second option, - 1 for the third = +1 so upvote anyway, I but also upvote the comment so it gets shown even when comments are collapsed and highlighted with a colorful number of upvotes.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, both practically and ethically. This would _not_ be artibrary cancellation. The best option is _not_ to "sort things out" a few hours before having to teach something you haven't studied. etc.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This question is on the "hot" list on other sites, so a lot of people (like me!) are coming in from other sites without the reputation _here_ to downvote, but enough to agree with the comment.

Comment: @mattdm Ahhhh, excellent point.

Comment: I think it would be better to cancel class without a stated reason than to lie about being sick. That sets a bad precedent.

Comment: Downvoting based on the suggestion of lying about being sick is so idealistic, I feel like only someone who has never once been in the labor force could do it.

Comment: @Jeff I just downvoted for suggesting lying about being sick. I worked full time for 32 years.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I wasn't making a literal statement, but I encourage you to explain why anyway.  The answer doesn't suggest it's a *good* strategy, but the OP has already put themselves in a place (5 hours before class with a need to sleep in there) where no good strategies apply.

Comment: @Jeff Ultimately, it comes down to my deeply held view that life is a non-zero-sum game. The world works better if people's statements can be accepted without doing a lot of checking. I prefer a world in which I can just tell an employer I'm sick, and be believed without having to get a doctor's note.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you took care of it well.

For those considering in the future, I'd say you ***can*** cancel class.  There's no need to be very specific in your reasoning for why to the students.
As a TA, I was to make a 4 hour drive back to campus after a weekend away, and my car wouldn't start.  Not much I could do.  Not a situation I was excited to explain.  But not one with much choice at that point.  It means less learning time, which is no good for anyone (if you are properly interested in seeing them learn as much as possible as well!).  But there are all kinds of reasons people cancel class, many where teachers don't want to go into details.  And even some potentially valid ones involved with class preparation (a large project/test you'd built the class time around suddenly disappearing into the computing void, vital class materials not coming in, etc).  It's not something you should consider lightly, but if it's important to cancel class, then it's important to cancel class.  You're fairly unlikely to get significant challenge.  The only ones who really might be in a situation to challenge you are your superiors.  But even in that less likely circumstance, you can try repeating the limited explanation... or give a full explanation (they may not be TOO happy with it, but they'll probably just have to take it, give a warning about being prepared, and move on).  If you you've done your best and you're really convinced it's the best option, you do what you have to do, you take any consequences it takes, and you move forward.  Quality teachers sometimes have to face unhappy individuals, and if it's your fault, that you didn't pay enough attention to the course plan or did not prepare soon enough, you commit to working hard so it doesn't happen again, and then you deal with the current fallout.  You can't change the past, you can only make the best choices in the current.  And if that means canceling classes, so be it.

But, indeed, **see if you can adapt your class so that you don't have to cancel** to get around the trouble.  Review, cover a topic scheduled for another time, focus on the background aspects that you do understand, show a video, whatever will *usefully* consume the time.  Usefully being the key word.  Cancelling isn't the worst option.  Wasting time is worse.  Maybe not to how you are thought of, but to the betterment of your students.

If you do have to cancel, try your best to **supplement the missed time**.  Send out extra homework.  Make a YouTube video lecture.  Put together an application project.  If the students are expected to check electronic medium, you can probably fairly expect them to do it (you could also put a printed copy of your message on the classroom door for any who may unaware come to the classroom).  If they aren't expected to keep track of media, you can probably still reasonably expect them to make up some of the lost time with a bit of extra homework later.  Meet them in the middle, you don't want to swamp their schedule, especially with busywork, but giving them, for instance, a 20 minute video lecture + practice problems posted later in the week when it was to be an hour class probably won't be seen as too problematic for most... and you can be a little more adaptable if there are some that maybe don't have scheduling flexibility to do more extra work outside of class later in the week.  The point is, you try to do your job the best you can, and be supportive to them in doing it, they'll meet you half way.  I believe every student did the replacement work that I sent out for that class that I missed 11 years ago.  Undergraduates usually are so excited to get an hour off classwork, they don't mind doing a bit of extra work at home!

**Not understanding material well can be a very dangerous situation**.  I saw one of the other answers or comments suggested that being transparent on such shortcomings would lead to revolt, but the alternative, pretending that you know it well when you don't, can be absolutely devastating.  In situations like a preset college course, maybe you don't tell them you're struggling.  But you also work very hard to get ahead of it.  Going in and trying to work a few "simple" problems when you're struggling with the topic is just asking for a mess.  The one thing worse than cancelling class or delaying (or even skipping) material is to come into class and teach it wrong, make repeated mistakes, and absolutely confuse everyone.  We've probably all had teachers come in and absolutely make a mess of problems, and we left understanding the material less than before.  I had a teacher in my major who repeatedly did that.  That's where you lose control of a class, when you pretend to know what you're doing but don't show it.  Your number one job as a teacher isn't keeping the schedule, but making sure you're *improving* upon any that they learn independently.  As such, in many courses, textbook reading is required.  Indeed, in many courses the the expectation isn't that they're necessarily reading it all the time before class.  But when they do reading, most students should at least a loose handle on the information.  Coming in and making mistakes is bound to destroy that.  If indeed you cancelled class, emphasize to them that this is the one time where the textbook reading is even more necessary, so that you are able to pick up moving ahead next week, and reduce the hit of the missed class.

I've certainly been hit with situations through the years where I had new material to suddenly teach.  As a private school teacher, I often substituted in a variety of courses.  Or in my own classes, like chemistry or history, I offered a little freedom to investigate any topics that particularly interested my students... and ended up doing cram sessions on stomach digestion or Native American tribes.  Students threw new-fangled common core math approaches at me, and occasionally it'd appear so abstruse that I needed to pass on it until next class to not waste time and focus.  No one expects us to know everything.  Even a major professor will get a question they don't know how to answer occasionally, or a problem that they'll manage to struggle with unexpectedly.  Instead of trying to force it, take a step back, tell them you'll look back into it further, and then follow up the next week, or online, (or directly to the student outside of class, if it's indeed an unnecessary tangent that will be more detriment than gain to other students).  Pretending to know something you don't seems the cardinal sin in teaching.  It suggests the students should have learn the same undercurrents of pride and dishonesty.  It may not be quite so fitting for college courses, **but there are definitely many teaching situations where you should admit to your students you don't perfectly understand**.  It shows them that you're not so different from them and need to work at it sometimes too**.  And ends up encouraging confidence and effort from the students who need it most.

And you did well.  If you're hit with a situation where you're just not making it, **don't be afraid to ask for help**.  You may be embarrassed, you may even look poor in the eyes of your superior, but it's better to do what is necessary than to pretend.  There's no guarantees you'll get the help, but there's often a wealth of assistance right at your front door if you'll just be bold enough to seek it.

Overall, you adapted.  You fought hard to overcome it, and you kept the best interest of your students at the front.  Decorum be darned, that's what teaching is all about.  And we need more teachers doing that!

Answer (score 6):

This semester, after a few months of teaching a very specialized but little known programming language (INSEL), students were pleased with my lessons but expressed the desire to learn something more well-known.

I know Ruby very well, and could write Ruby code in my sleep. It's not really widespread in academia though, so I feared they would also complain about it. In comparison, Python is probably used in every university on Earth.

For some reason, I claimed "I could teach you **RUBY** or (whispering) Python, if you want". All the students cheered "YEAH!!! PYTHON!!!!". The big problem was : I didn't know Python at all! The syntax is often similar to Ruby, but that was about all I knew about it.

I had less than 2 weeks to learn it before teaching it. It was stressful but exhiliarating to learn so much new material in such a short time. I used https://learnpythonthehardway.org/ and began answering easy questions on stackoverflow.

I also was very honest with the students, telling them I still had a lot to learn about the language. I also warned them that I very well might not know how to answer a question. If that happened, we would train a very useful skill together : Using Google with the correct search terms, finding the corresponding StackOverflow thread, picking the correct answer and adapting it to our problem.

During 3 full days of hands-on Python programming, it only happened once. Students were happy and learned a lot. They asked very insightful questions, which often helped me learn the language better. Depending on their progress and feedback, it was also easier to adapt the next lesson to their needs.

So yes, you can do it, you just need to be very honest, humble and motivated. Be sure to bring enough material (books or laptop+Internet). That way, if you don't know an answer, you can involve the students in the process of looking for a solution. You will learn something, they will train an essential skill and time will pass faster that way ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas sprung to mind when I read about your dilemma.

1) Skip ahead to a topic that you *are* ready to handle. That would give you a couple days to keep working on the topic that has you flummoxed. You can always go back to it next week.

2) Buy some time by holding a “review session”. Take a handful of the more recent topics covered, and reexamine those topics. One good way to do this is to come up with a complicated problem that requires a couple different techniques covered. That way, this becomes a worthwhile lesson in how to synthesize some of the techniques recently taught in the class.

3) Try turning this into an active learning exercise. Typically, you would solve a problem in front of the class. This time, have the students guide you into solving the problem. Chances are you’ve got a few bright students in your class that can crack this nut.

Admittedly, #3 is a risky proposition. If the students ultimately encounter as much trouble as you’ve had in figuring this out, it might make for an awkward moment in the classroom. But I have tried this before, and it was successful. (Even if they can’t solve the problem completely on their own, a student might provide a nudge in the right direction that helps you figure it out on the fly.)

If things don’t work out how you’d like, you can still “save face”, as long as you’re able to figure it out down the road and eventually explain to the students what you were unable to solve during the “active learning” session.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you or your department is very disorganized. That "winging" mentality is what got you in this situation in the first place. I suggest you change the way you approach things, get rid of the "winging" mentality. Know your sh*t. Teaching is not theatrics, it's not a show. And for the teachers that believe it is about theatrics they're garbage.

Comment: My department is incredibly disorganised (see above comment about my work over Intersession). I have been a math tutor for 8 years for an incredible range of students, privately, as well head math tutor of my undergrad and working for a tutoring company placed in low income public high schools. "Winging it" in that sense was always part of the job as I never knew what type of material, or attitudes, a student would have in a session. As far as my work as a TA, this is the only day I have been unprepared and normally have solutions available to students days prior to class.